# single PCRE regex to swap '0' for '1' and '1' for '0' at a specific location in a string

Tags: regex, pcre

My input string has either a '0' or a '1' at a specific location. 
If it's a '1', I want to replace it with '0' and likewise if it's '0' replace it with a '1'.

Working on the assumption 'x' will never occur and my string is just a single character, I can do it with 3 regexes like so:

```
s/0/x/
s/1/0/
s/x/0/
```

but that's pretty messy. I was wondering if PCRE has something fancy that can do this with just one expression?

Comment: What **language** are you doing this in?

Comment: using `grep -P`. I'd understood that pcre is pretty much consistent across languages? If a language does it differently, isn't it no longer true pcre?

Comment: `s/x/y/` is a string substitution operation which is supported in many programming languages. It is not a feature of regular expressions in general, or PCRE and/or `grep` in particular. Regex is a formalism for matching strings, not for modifying them (though some implementations dizzy this distinction).

Comment: You can't achieve this with regex alone. You need to use callback function in the replacement part. In php this would be achieved by `php_replace_callback` function and in python this would be achieved by using `lambda` function inside `re.sub`. In perl, this would be achieved by using `e` modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presence of an other x in the string is not a problem since you don't need it:

```
sed 'y/01/10/' input >output
```

or without sed:

```
tr 01 10 <input >output
```

I'm posting this from the comment by [@Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284930/single-pcre-regex-to-swap-0-for-1-and-1-for-0-at-a-specific-location-in/30285036?noredirect=1#comment48668304_30285036) as Community Wiki because I think it's the best answer, even above the one I posted myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like

```
perl -pe  's/([01])/ 0+!$1 /ge' file
```

where `$1` is the captured string, `!` produces its negation, and `0+` forces a numeric context. The `/g` flag says to  process every match on a line, and the `/e` causes the substitution expression to be evaluated as Perl code.

[IdeOne.com demo](http://ideone.com/3x8bim)

Comment: In Java, this produces `0+!0` for `0`

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Indeed, this is a Perl answer, not a Java answer. Here I was thinking I have a good capacity for fantasy, but I cannot figure out how you would even get the idea to try this in Java.

Comment: Just testing the PCRE-ness of Java

Comment: But only the actual regex `([01])` is PCRE here; the rest is Perl.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Here's a Python version which hopefully better spells out what's happening here, much of it completely implicitly in Perl. (I didn't want to use `eval`, which would have been required for a more faithful translation.) https://ideone.com/eCx33s

Comment: (And, of course, the `0+` is pointless in Python because it doesn't do anything useful in a language which doesn't silently convert its second term to a number when it's not.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a gnu-awk command to flip 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 in the given input:

```
awk -v RS='[01]' '{ORS = xor(RT, 1)} 1' <<< "abc1foo0bar"
abc0foo1bar

awk -v RS='[01]' '{ORS = xor(RT, 1)} 1' <<< "1"
0

awk -v RS='[01]' '{ORS = xor(RT, 1)} 1' <<< "0"
1

awk -v RS='[01]' '{ORS = xor(RT, 1)} 1' <<< "foo1"
foo0

awk -v RS='[01]' '{ORS = xor(RT, 1)} 1' <<< "0bar"
1bar
```

This awk command uses a custom record separator as 0 or 1 and uses [bitwise `xor` operation on `RT` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your use case, but what about using sed?

```
echo 'ah1s' | sed 's/0/x/;s/1/0/;s/x/1/'
echo 'ah0s' | sed 's/0/x/;s/1/0/;s/x/1/'
```

Comment: you need to add `g` modifier. What if `x` present in the input string?

Comment: If you take a closer look at the question, you'll see that the given assumption was that "x" will never occur in the input string

Comment: That will only replace the first occurrence. You probably want to add a `/g` flag to each of your substiutions.

Comment: Once again: If you take a closer look at the question, you'll see that the given assumption was that "the input string is a single character"

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree: if the requirements are about changing something at a specific position, a global modifier won't limit its action at the specific position given. Your assumption is correct in a general way, but in this case I just obey the requirements

Comment: The presence of an other x in the string is not a problem since you don't need it: `sed 'y/01/10/'` or without sed: `tr 01 10`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Please post that as an answer; it definitely gets my vote.

Comment: @tripleee: sorry I can't because I must go to the market to buy rabbits.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Posted a CW answer instead then; I'll remove it if you change your mind.